# Entity Framework Core 2 auto generated columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this model:

```
public class Model
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ModelId {get;set;}
    public int Variable {get;set;}
 }
```

I want both variables to be auto incremented on add.
If I put `[Key]` or `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` also on the Variable property, EF Core says that you can't have 2 identity columns.

I have also tried with `FluentAPI`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity().Property(variable => variable).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

but i still get the same error.

How can I have 2 auto incremented values on add?

Comment: Why do you need two auto incrementing columns on a single table? SQL Server does not support this.

Comment: I have many properties in that class Model, but those two are not (and shouldn't be) included in the request. So the client makes a request, and those two properties should be auto increment in the database.

Comment: I understand, but why do you need two columns for that? What is your requirement?

Comment: The client wants those two columns autoincrement, and i tried to do that. When i add them, should i take the last Variable count, and make Variable = Variable ++ ?

Comment: If you require a second column to have an automatic value based on another column's value, you may want to look into **computed columns**.

Comment: How are you auto-incrementing those columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SqlServer allows only one identity column per table. But it allows you to define and use as much [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences) as you wish:

> A sequence generates a sequential numeric values in the database. Sequences are not associated with a specific table.

Following the above EF Core documentation link, you can instruct EF to create sequence and use it for your `Variable` column like this (as the documentation states, "*You can not configure a sequence using Data Annotations"*):

```
modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("VariableSequence");

modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().Property(e => e.Variable)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR VariableSequence");
```

Answer (score -1):

You tried not to put anything and make the model like this:

```
 public class Model
 {    
    public long? ModelId {get;set;}

    public int? Variable {get;set;}
 }
```

And model Builder:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ModelId, e.Variable} )
                    .HasName("PK_Model");

            });
```

Comment: autoincrement implement on database.

Comment: I tried also the composite key method, doesn't work.  If i make the second property auto increment on database, the first column will not be identity anymore.